# SBCL surprise lapse into floating point?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, org-babel

Consider the following code in Common Lisp:

```
  (defun range (max &key (min 0) (step 1))
    (loop for n from min below max by step
          collect n))
  (reduce #'* (range 61 :min 1))
```

This gives the expected bignum value of 60!, namely

```
8320987112741390144276341183223364380754172606361245952449277696409600000000000000
```

However, the following code, which doesn't include any floating-point coercions that I can see, produces a floating-point answer:

```
  (defun fact (n)
    (if (= 0 n)
        1
        (* n (fact (- n 1)))))

  (fact 60)
  8.32098711274139e+81
```

The questions are "why?" and "how can I write a straightforward, recursive `fact` in SBCL (Steel-Bank Common Lisp) that produces a bignum result?"

Comment: It doesn't happen for me. What version of SBCL are you using?

Comment: Try `(setf *print-pretty* nil)` before the call to `(fact 60)`. It seems a problem of some printing parameter that forces the printing of an integer as a floating point number. Your function actually returns an integer in any Common Lisp implementation, including SBCL.

Comment: can't reproduce it either in SBCL 1.3.0 on ARM..

Comment: can't reproduce it either in SBCL 1.3.0 on OS X.

Comment: It's happening in org-babel / slime: ` #+RESULTS:
  : Emacs version: GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21)
  :  of 2015-04-10 on builder10-9.porkrind.org
  : org version: 8.3.1`

Comment: @Reb.Cabin that is the emacs version not SBCL's version. run `(lisp-implementation-version)` to get SBCL's version

Comment: @Renzo *print-pretty* didn't work in emacs SLIME -- I have uploaded my .org file here at this gist https://gist.github.com/rebcabin/5b3208cc3d431d04651a (notice how Github formatted it automatically into markdown -- a nice surprise!) --- this appears to be a SLIME issue because it DOES work when i run SBCL directly in a terminal window.

Comment: @PuercoPop -- my SBCL is 1.3.1 as reported by `(lisp-implementation-version)`

Comment: I now believe this to be an ORG-BABEL issue because it does work correctly, even without @Renzo's `*print-pretty*` suggestion, in the SLIME REPL in Emacs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The coercion happens on the emacs side. [ob-lisp.el](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/ob-lisp.el#n96) calls read on the result. Try evaluating this on the *scratch* buffer to see for your self

```
(read "8320987112741390144276341183223364380754172606361245952449277696409600000000000000")
```

Comment: What's surprising is that *one time* I got the bignum to repeatedly print correctly in the org-babel buffer (that's why I originally found this mysterious and wrote up the question).  I cannot repro it.